# Изменение формата вывода вещественных чисел и Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `QTableView`, связанное с `QSqlTableModel` (может быть это и не важно, но для ясности пусть будет)
Нужно чтобы вещественные числа типа `float` или `double` выводились не в формате типа `1,24215e+4`, а в формате, который может быть легко воспринят пользователем `12421,5`. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно реализовывать свою модель данных и в ней переопределять метод data, в котором работать с отображением, пару ссылок - https://habrahabr.ru/post/171443/, https://rsdn.org/forum/cpp.qt/5610842.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно реализовать [прокси-модель](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html). Она нужна для перенаправления запросов от представления к основной модели с возможностью изменения отображаемых данных. В прокси-модели нужно переопределить метод [data](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html#data), который будет читать основную модель, изменять представление и возвращать строковые данные (переведённые в QVariant).

Пример реализации метода `data`:

```
MyProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex, int role = Qt::DisplayRole)
{
    if (!proxyIndex.isValid())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }
    float value = m_sourceModel->data(proxyIndex, role).toFloat();
    QString proxyValue = QString::number(value, 'g', 2);
    return proxyValue;
}
```

где m_sourceModel - указатель на модель, заданную методом [setSourceModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html#setSourceModel).

Comment: Для получения данных нужно конвертировать прокси индекс в индекс исходной модели: функция mapToSource(). Далее можно использовать sourceIndex.data() для получения данных. Указатель на исходную модель не нужен

Comment: И, наверное, стоит упомянуть, что нужно использовать QIdentityProxyModel, иначе придется многие виртуальные функции реализовывать самому